# Vue.js - Select / dropdown selected item vm binding is not working (bootstrap-vue)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a simple vue that binds the selected item from a select/dropdown to a property in the vm.

I haven't been able to find a clear and simple example of how this is down when using an options collection that is also in the view model.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Select box</h1>
        <b-dropdown id="ddCommodity"
                    name="ddCommodity"
                    v-model="ddTestVm.ddTestSelectedOption"
                    text="Select Item"
                    variant="primary"
                    class="m-md-2" v-on:change="changeItem">
            <b-dropdown-item disabled value="0">Select an Item</b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item v-for="option in ddTestVm.options":selected="option.value == 'LME/ST_TNI_ALL'":value="option.value">{{option.text}}</b-dropdown-item>           
        </b-dropdown> <span>Selected: {{ ddTestVm.ddTestSelectedOption }}</span>
 </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        components: {

        },
        data() {
            return {
                someOtherProperty: null,
                ddTestVm: {
                    originalValue: [],
                    ddTestSelectedOption: "Value1",
                    disabled: false,
                    readonly: false,
                    visible: true,
                    color: "",
                    options: [
                        {
                            "value": "Value1",
                            "text": "Value1Text"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "Value2",
                            "text": "Value2Text"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "Value3",
                            "text": "Value3Text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },        
        methods: {
            changeItem: async function () {
            //grab some remote data
                try {
                    let response = await this.$http.get('https://www.example.com/api/' + this.ddTestVm.ddTestSelectedOption + '.json');
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.someOtherProperty = response.data;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {

        },
        async created() {

        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Regardless of what i've tried i cannot get the selected value in the dropdown to change the ddTestSelectedOption property of the vm.

Could anyone assist on this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`b-dropdown` in `bootstrap-vue` does not support `v-model`. As [the documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown) states:

> Dropdowns are toggleable, contextual overlays for displaying lists of
> links and actions in a dropdown menu format.

In other words, `b-dropdown` is essentially a UI component for displaying a menu or similar set of options.

I expect what you want is [`b-form-select`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select/).

That said, you could add a click handler to the options that sets the value.

```
  <b-dropdown-item v-for="option in ddTestVm.options" 
                    :key="option.value" 
                    :value="option.value"
                    @click="ddTestVm.ddTestSelectedOption = option.value">
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/y31zkqnwkz).

Comment: well that's embarrassing :) Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas why :on-change="changeItem" would not be working? The event never seems to fire.

Comment: @billyjean For what component? Neither `b-form-select` or `b-dropdown` emit an `on-change` event or accept an `on-change` property.

Answer (score 2):

Only [b-form-select](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-select) can achieve the selected value behaviour.

Non-Selected Value Preview:
[image]

Selected Value Preview:
[image]

Sample Code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></b-form-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: null,
        options: [
          { value: 1, text: 'Please select an option' },
          { value: 2, text: 'This is First option' },
          { value: 3, text: 'Selected Option' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing you need b-form-select

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></b-form-select>
    <b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options" size="sm" class="mt-3"></b-form-select>

    <div class="mt-3">Selected: <strong>{{ selected }}</strong></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selected: null,
        options: [
          { value: null, text: 'Please select an option' },
          { value: 'a', text: 'This is First option' },
          { value: 'b', text: 'Selected Option' },
          { value: { C: '3PO' }, text: 'This is an option with object value' },
          { value: 'd', text: 'This one is disabled', disabled: true }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to leave a comment, but code example looks pale there :)

Yes, `b-dropdown` does not properly support Vue model, but it doesn't have to.

For those still interested in exactly dropdown (f.e. because it looks fancier), consider:

```
    <b-dropdown :text="$i18n.locale" >
      <b-dropdown-item v-for="(lang, i) in $i18n.availableLocales" :key="`Lang${i}`" :value="lang" v-on:click="$i18n.locale = lang;" >{{lang}}</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
```

Slecifically `v-on:click`, which can handle the model value change for you.